# What is the difference between multinomial and categorical distribution?

Tags: probability

Both seem to result in one of k different separated outcomes, and Wikipedia says these are often conflated. Despite reading the explanation of the difference on the article about [multinomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), I still have trouble understanding what the difference really is.

Answer (score 37):

The multinomial distribution is when there are **multiple** identical independent trials where each trial has $k$ possible outcomes.

The categorical distribution is when there is **only one** such trial.

Comment: +1. It corresponds the distinction between the binomial and the Bernoulli distributions: a sample size of $n$ compared with a sample size of $1$

Comment: Multinomial : Binomial :: Categorical : Bernoulli

Comment: I thought the name *multinomial* was opposed to *binomial*. i.e. binomial distribution deals with two category case and multinomial distribution with several categories, in both cases having multiple trials. The answer somehow suggests to me that the *multi* part of multinomial refers to it dealing with >1 independent trials.

Comment: Otherwise agree with the answer BTW.

Comment: It is the multinational distribution with parameter n = 1.

Comment: worth noting that Categorical is sometimes called Multinoulli.

Answer (score 10):

Think of it like this proportion:-

Bernoulli:Binomial::Categorical:Multinomial

So, just like Bernoulli distribution gives us the probability for a binary variable at each instance while Binomial returns it for N examples, Categorical distribution gives us the probability for a k-classifying variable at each instance while a Multinomial distribution returns it for N examples.

Thus: Categorical(Pk) = Multinomial(Pk, 1)