# a set of 2 questions: what is the scenario in which rolling dice could be treated as a multinomial distribution and 2 multinoulli distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, machine-learning

This post talks about ["the difference between multinomial and categorical distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/966466/673026)" without any concrete examples, and the answer have not been accepted yet.

section 3.9 of the "Deep Learning Book" [Ian Goodfellow and Yoshua Bengio and Aaron Courville. Deep Learning](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/) distinguishes the difference:

> The multinoulli distribution is a special case of the multinomial distribution

without any concrete examples either.

It seems that this [CMU Machine Learning Course](https://youtu.be/tpmdcJYnAyQ?t=1307) consider rolling dice as multinomial  distribution while I think might be multinoulli distribution per the "Deep Learning Book".multinomial

Am I missing something?

in other words, could someone give an concrete example to illustrate the scenario in which rolling dice could be treated as a multinomial  distribution and some other scenarios in which rolling dice could be treated as a multinoulli distribution

Comment: Your question is hard to follow...I think you are jumbling your terms.  Please edit for clarity.

Comment: @lulu  I've updated my question, would you please take a loot at that?

Comment: I think your confusion is purely semantic.  For a two state outcome, a Bernoulli process is the same as a one trial Binomial process.  Same thing here.  One roll of a die is either a multinoulli process or a one trial multinomial process.

Comment: @lulu thanks for your reply. in this context, shall I treat 2 rolls of a die **a 2 trial 
 multinomial process** which is not a multinoulli process, right?

Comment: Just think about the two state case.  A two trial binomial process is not the same as a bernoulli process.  But...don't get hung up on vocabulary.  People have given names to some standard distributions that seem to arise a lot, but the important thing is the underlying distribution...not the name we give to it.

Comment: consider rolling a die 2 times, is this a multinomial process which consists of 2 single multinoulli processes, right?

Comment: It depends what you do with the outcome!  In a standard multinomial process, you count the occurrences of each outcome.  If, say, you roll a $1$ and then a $6$, that would be $(1,0,0,0,0,1)$ with, I think, obvious notation.  Same if you roll a $6$ and then a $1$.  However, you could also keep track of the order.  That would be another multinoulli process, since you'd now have $36$ disjoint outcomes each with its own probability (uniform in this case, assuming a fair die).

Comment: But you see  the semantics problem.  I could view the first process as mulinoulli as well, just assign a probability to each of the $21$ possible outcomes. That would be non-uniform even with a fair die as $(1,0,0,0,0,1)$ has twice the probability as $(2,0,0,0,0,0)$.  This is why getting hung up on vocabulary is a bad idea.

Comment: @lulu  Assume I use the outcome to compute the MAP estimate, as that [CMU Machine Learning Course](https://youtu.be/Mq0UpzWMe_o?t=2259) do. then I got (1,6,...), which consists of 2 single multinoulli processes, right?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to watch an hour + video .  It still seems to me that you are hung up on vocabulary.  The usual multinomial process just keeps tracks of the running results of independent trials of a multinoulli process.  That's a very standard thing to do.